# MATLAB - get fieldnames of each element

Tags: arrays, matlab, field

Given when I call `fieldnames(md)`, I have a list of all element from class md.

Now each element in `md` is many subclasses with their own sub-elements, for example the first item that `fieldnames(md)` returns called `mesh`, and when I call `fieldnames(mesh)`, I get another list of string contains all items from `mesh` and that's it.

The goal here is to write all the items from all `md` subclasses to a text file.

I tried the following:

```
 mfields = fieldnames(md);
 fid = fopen('textfile.txt','w'); 
 for i=1:numel(mfields)
       for j=1:numel(fieldnames(mfields{i}))
            fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',fieldnames(mfields{i}))
       end
 end
```

But apparently fieldnames doesn't take `char` as argument. I'm new to matlab so please suggest if there is other function that does this job

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 mfields = fieldnames(md);
 fid = fopen('textfile.txt','w'); 
 for i=1:numel(mfields)
       %// Check if the field is a struct itself, otherwise it will not have any subfields.
       if isstruct(md.(mfields{i}))
           subfields=fieldnames(md.(mfields{i}));
       else
          %// Put a space so that it will still display the root field name when there are no subfields
          subfields = {' '};
       end

       %// Loop through all the subfields
       for j=1:numel(subfields)
            fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',subfields{j})   %// Or  fprintf(fid,'%s\t%s\r\n',mfields{i}, subfields{j})
       end
 end
```

Comment: got error in the fprintf line: undefined variable "fieldnames" or class "fieldnames.x"  x is the first element in the cell

Comment: @Herious did you try latest edit?. Also check out the alternative version in the comment, might be useful

Comment: @Herious Although this will still error if you have any fields in `md` that **DONT** have fieldnames. Is this the case? Will have to add a check for that.

Comment: Now I got error at 4th line: Undefined function 'fieldnames' for input arguments of type 'char'

Comment: @Herious Edited again, try now. It's difficult to debug without knowing the exact format of your struct though, perhaps you could add that to your question?

Comment: thanks for the help but I think it falls to the else in my case :(

Comment: @Herious it would help a lot if you could post a minimal working example of your case as I've tested this on my side and it is working now

Comment: for security reason I cannot post the codes, but basically this class has a `properties` with all the field set to 0, the it will call another function to get data for these field, like mesh = mesh()